# How to fix the position of image inside UIButton?

Tags: ios, swift, cocoa-touch, uibutton

Let's say we have an image with size 22 x 22. We also have a button with size 260 x 44.
This button will be resized horizontally so that it is always 16 px from the edges of screen.

I want to fix the position of the image inside the button so that it is vertically centered and 10 px from the left button edge, regardless of the button size **in design time.** This button will be resized to fit iPhone 5/6/6+

I don't want to calculate content/image/title/edgeInsets for this button outside the button in some controller's viewDidLayoutSubviews that feels wrong. This is not VCs responsibility.
I am not going to subclass `UIButton`, it's a class cluster, all right?

Am I really stuck with implementing my own Button from UIControl? 
Or did I miss some possible configuration of UIButton class?

Comment: did you try `contentHorizontalAlignment` and `contentEdgeInsets`? By setting them to left and defining the padding with the edgeInsets, I think you are done?

Comment: Thats was it! :) `contentHorizontalAlignment ` works well. Thank you.

Comment: @Christian Please post it as answer, so others can find it easily.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With `contentHorizontalAlignment` you can set the alignment of the image to the left, with `contentEdgeInsets` you can define a padding from the border (as mentioned in my comment above).